# Same ZMQ_IDENTITY for multiple Subcribers

Tags: uuid, zeromq, pyzmq

I am building a zeromq PUB-SUB pattern with lots of subscribers to one publisher.
I want to build durable Subscribers, so I found out about the ZMQ_IDENTITy socket-option.

What should I take into account when choosing the value for the Identity? 
And can I take the same for all subscribers?
Since they are all the same type but on different machines, that should be a problem, right? 
Furthermore, are UUIDs only generated vie inproc service as in the zguide example explained?

Comment: don't use zmq identities (durable socket).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the IDENTITY option. Durable subscribers were removed from ZeroMQ/3.x so your application would be stuck on the 2.x version.

The reason that durable subscribers are so bad we removed them is that they consume arbitrary amounts of memory on the publisher (the messages have to stay somewhere), which leads too easily to out-of-memory, the fastest way to kill your pubsub system for all subscribers.

If you want a durable subscriber model, you can construct it quite easily on top of ZeroMQ, and there's an full worked example in the Guide (Clone pattern).

I'm not sure if anyone's built a durable pubsub broker over ZeroMQ, it would be a fun exercise and not so difficult.

Comment: Thanks Pieter, I'll try the clone pattern.